# "Да" бывают разные: могут просить и не просить запятую перед. Какой случай у меня?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, частицы

> И в этот чудесный, погожий денёк они выглядели как сущие подростки,
>   жадно и изобретательно уплетая десерт на солнышке, да в дорогой их
>   сердцу компании милого, добродушного пса.

Comment: Как — тоже настойчиво просит.

Comment: Не-а. Выглядели сущими подростками. Иначе что здесь делает определение "сущие"?

Comment: Принял это началом оборота: от «как» и до конца фразы. Может, я не так уж и неправ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*И в этот чудесный, погожий денёк они выглядели как сущие подростки, жадно и изобретательно уплетая десерт на солнышке, **да ещё** в дорогой их сердцу компании милого, добродушного пса.*

Здесь ДА скорее **присоединительный союз,** но это значение в данной конструкции неочевидно, поэтому желательно его дополнительно обозначить местоимением ***ещё***.

Из словаря:

**ДА 2. (присоединяет предл. и чл. предл.).** Указывает на развитие, дополнение, пояснение высказанной мысли или характеристику, оценку сказанного. Обидели, да ещё как! Мало того, что задержали ни за что ни про что, да к тому же и штраф наложили. Такая женщина плачет, да притом по пустякам!